# Selenium crashes Firefox, how to reset the used profile / where is the default profile?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test project which is powered by `Cucumber`, `Selenium` and `Java`

**Problem:** Firefox crashes when it is started by selenium, after i click on okay on that popup firefox runs normal. This problem is only on my maschine. On our integration server it runs just fine. I think my `Firefox Profile` is defect.

**Question:** Where is the profile which is used by selenium locate? I use windows by the way. And is there a way to reset it?

**Infos:** 
I instantiate the WebDriver like this:

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
FirefoxDriver ff = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
```

And i use the newest firefox

Thanks in advance, if further information is needed, just leave a comment and i will profide it if possible.

Comment: My Selenium automated Firefox also crashed after update Firefox to latest. My production servers running older version of Firefox (auto update disabled) runs normal.

Comment: for me it is running fine after i klick okay on the first crash popup and it persists since 1-2 firefox updates

Comment: In other words, selenium 2.46 is out, it is compatible with the latest firefox (38 currently).

Comment: Oh! That's great! Let me update my program and test again. I didn't check it every day.

Comment: okay thanks, i should have seen that, will try it out now

Comment: this worked for me -> updating selenium was the solution, thx to @alecxe